# Undefined reference to my derived class using 3 sub classes

Tags: c++, derived-class

I have a default class `Barista` which I want as the default, and then I have derived types of `Barista`s to go along with it.

```cpp
class Barista 
{
public:
  Barista();
  virtual void getOrder();
  virtual void intro(){cout << "";}
};

class JuniorBarista: public Barista
{
public:
  JuniorBarista();
  void getOrder() override;
  void intro(){cout << "Hello my name is" << name_ << "What can I get you?" << endl;};
private:
  string name_ = "Joe";
};

class SeniorBarista: public Barista 
{
public:
  SeniorBarista();
  void getOrder() override;
  void intro(){cout << "Hello my name is" << name_ << "What can I get you?" << endl;};
private: 
  string name_ = "jan";
};

class ManagerBarista: public Barista 
{
public:
  ManagerBarista();
  void getOrder() override;
  void intro(){cout << "Hello my name is" << name_ << "What can I get you?" << endl;};
  
private:
  string name_ = "jon";
};
```

I'm trying to call the `intro()` method of the `JuniorBarista` in `main()` and I am getting an "undefined reference" error.

I'm trying to call my function like this:

```cpp
Barista *b;
b = new Barista();
b = new JuniorBarista();

b->intro();
```

I'm unsure of what exactly I'm doing wrong and would love an explanation why I am getting this error.

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Jaden\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUPD7MN.o:lab11p1.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Barista::Barista()'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Jaden\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUPD7MN.o:lab11p1.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `JuniorBarista::JuniorBarista()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: in your classes `Barista();` declares a constructor but doesn't define it. perhaps you just wanted `Barista() {}` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring non-default, non-inline constructors in your classes, but where are the implementations for those constructors?  The linker can't find them, hence the "unresolved" errors.  If you are not going to actually implement the constructors, declare them as `default`, eg:

```cpp
class Barista 
{
public:
  Barista() = default;
  ...
};

class JuniorBarista: public Barista
{
public:
  JuniorBarista() = default;
  ...
};

class SeniorBarista: public Barista 
{
public:
  SeniorBarista() = default;
  ...
};

class ManagerBarista: public Barista 
{
public:
  ManagerBarista() = default;
...
};
```

Same with `getOrder()`, too.  Each of your classes has a non-inline `getOrder()` declared, but where are the implementations?

---

Also, you have a memory leak.  You are creating a `Barista` object via `new` but you are not 'delete`'ing it afterwards.

```cpp
Barista *b;
b = new Barista(); // <-- here
b = new JuniorBarista();

b->intro();
```

You need to get rid of that statement:

```cpp
Barista *b;
b = new JuniorBarista();

b->intro();
```

And don't forget to `delete b` when you are done using it:

```cpp
Barista *b;
b = new JuniorBarista();

b->intro();
...
delete b;
```

Note, when `delete`'ing an object via a pointer to a base class, the base class needs to have a `virtual` destructor so that all derived destructors are called properly, but your code is currently missing that:

```cpp
class Barista 
{
public:
  ...
  virtual ~Barista() = default; // <-- add this!
  ...
};
```

Comment: This solved all of my problems. I now noticed I made a lot of careless errors when originally writing my code. Thank you for fully describing my problems and giving a useful fix.